# My computer hangs on Copy & Paste

Tags: freeze, windows-server-2003, copy-paste

My machine hangs for about 7 seconds before pasting the data, even if the data was very small. It doesn't happen all the time though.

My environment:

- Windows Server 2003
- working a lot with remote desktop connection and do `copy & paste` between my machine and the remote desktop.
- Most of the time happens when `copy & paste` between two apps (e.g.: Excel and management studio, Notepad and Microsoft word, etc-).

What leads to such an issue?

Comment: Try disabling clipboard integration with your RDP client when you make the connection and see if this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What would cause it is that tt is not only copying and pasting between the remote applications, it is copying it across the network to your local computer's clipboard.

As Mike Insch said, if you can do without cutting and pasting between the local and remote computers, you could disable it in RDP, but if not, this is expected behavior. It happens to me all the time when I copy screenshots over the WAN.